# How to get rid of VIEW in this request

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE VIEW A1 AS
SELECT client_ID , COUNT(dog_id)
FROM test_clients
GROUP BY client_ID
HAVING COUNT(dog_id)=2;
```

```sql
CREATE VIEW A2 AS
SELECT filial , COUNT(A1.client_ID)
FROM A1
JOIN test_clients USING (client_ID)
GROUP BY filial
HAVING COUNT(A1.client_ID)>10;
```

```sql
SELECT COUNT(filial)
FROM A2;
```

As far as I understand, this can be done through a subquery, but how?

Comment: Technically, it's called a derived table. Basically, in your second query, you would use `from (<first query>) a1`, everything else stays the same.

Comment: [starball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/starball), Thank you, but isn't it possible to insert the first VIEW (A1) using JOIN into the second VIEW (A2) and do the same with the third part by inserting into it, what will come out of VIEW(A2) also using JOIN?

Comment: In english, would this be: `the number of filials with more than 10 clients, each of which has exactly 2 dogs`?

Comment: [Эрик Джордж](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9980357/eric-george), да, вы правы

Comment: Just to check; do you know that where you have `COUNT(client_id)` it will count each ***row*** (where client_id is not null), not each ***distinct client***? As you've already asserted that you only want clients with two dogs, that means you could be counting each client twice? Do you, perhaps, want `COUNT(DISTINCT client_id)`?

Comment: @MatBailie: Highly indicated check. Maybe the schema definition ensures unique clients per shop? Then it works as is. Goes to show the importance of exact table definitions once again ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burns down to:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM  (
   SELECT 1
   FROM  (
      SELECT client_id
      FROM   test_clients
      GROUP  BY 1
      HAVING count(dog_id) = 2
      ) a1
   JOIN   test_clients USING (client_id)
   GROUP  BY filial
   HAVING count(*) > 10
   ) a2;
```

Assuming `filial` is defined `NOT NULL`.

Probably faster to use a window function and get rid of the self-join:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM  (
   SELECT 1
   FROM  (
      SELECT filial
           , count(dog_id) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id) AS dog_ct
      FROM   test_clients
      ) a1
   WHERE  dog_ct = 2
   GROUP  BY filial
   HAVING count(*) > 10
   ) a2;
```

Depending on your exact table definition we might be able to optimize a bit further ...

Comment: [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter),Excellent solution, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

A slight refractor of Erwin's suggestion, just for you to play around with...

The outer query works because...

- the inner query happens first
- the WHERE clause happens next
- then the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses
- then the SELECT clause *(so the `COUNT() OVER ()`)*
- finally the DISTINCT

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  COUNT(filial) OVER ()
FROM
(
  SELECT
    filial,
    client_id,
    COUNT(dog_id) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id) AS client_dog_ct
  FROM
    test_clients
)
  count_dogs
WHERE
  client_dog_ct = 2
GROUP BY
  filial
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT client_id) > 10
```

You may or may not want the `COUNT(DISTINCT client_id)`, its not clear. So, play with that too.

I'm not saying it's any better, just that it's different and might help your learning.

Comment: @АндрейБаев That's (your deleted comment code) effectively what Erwin wrote, but you've got extras which you don't need. For example, you don't need to include `COUNT(A1.client_id)` in your SELECT clause, you can still use it in just the HAVING clause. Also, there's no need to count the `filial` column if it can't be `NULL`, which is why Erwin just selected `1` and used `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: The query in my answer follows the same logic as Erwin's answer, but also "abuses" DISTINCT and a window function to avoid nesting the query one level deeper. It won't save any execution costs, but it's sometimes a useful trick to write concise code, and very useful for learning the order of precidence of the different clauses.

Comment: [MatBailie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie) i apologize for the deleted comments, I wanted to make them readable, I didn't expect you to have time to read them, thank you for the clarifications, you helped me a lot.